# Google Storage Json Api - access "folders" from api fails?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am having problems accessing objects that use slashes through the api.  For example I have objects with the names "folder1/folder2/name".  When I use this with the api I get a 400 bad request.  Is this not supported yet by the Api?  or is a special character needed?  This also fails for me on the API explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a URL encoding issue. The object name is a single URL path part, and thus all slashes in the name need to be %-encoded. (i.e., folder1%2ffolder2%2fname)

API explorer, unfortunately, has a known issue (reported internally) with storage.objects.get. The method returns actual file data, and the API explorer is expecting JSON metadata and things go poorly from there.